# Cross Account EC2 Role Access to Read S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've been trying to get cross account ec2 role authorisation working for a while now but seem to be hitting a bit of a dead end. We currently have cross account user authentication which is working well, however expanding that to cross account ec2 role access doesn't seem possible as far as I can tell?

I came across the following [Cross Account Article](http://nclouds.com/blog/aws-cross-account-service-access-roles-temp-keys/), which basically undertook the same steps I had with similar results. Has a workaround for this come to fruition yet, or is it still required to use the Use-STSRole powershell/aws assume-role trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our use case it required amending the bucket policy to trust the account principal, rather than a specific role within it, and then controlling who was allowed that access in the usual IAM role manner.

For reference, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_policy-examples.html#example-delegate-xaccount-S3 and sample bucket policy below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Development Read-only Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "012345678910"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but I think the problem is related to the KMS key permissions.